# what does executenonquery return with multiple update statements

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure (Microsoft Sql Server).  NOCOUNT is OFF.
I have multiple update statements in the stored procedure.
I call the stored procedure from my C# application using executenonquery.
The problem I am experiencing is that all 4 update statements run with no error, but the executenonquery is returning -1.  What should the executenonquery return in this case (4 sequential update statements)?  I have no triggers defined in the database.

What am I missing ?
Thanks.

Comment: -1 is correctly returned because you are not executing an UPDATE (which would return a row count) you are executing an SP that is executing an UPDATE.

Comment: have a read here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx